# activesupport-2.3.11 conflicts with activesupport (>= 3.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, legacy

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project that a former programmer created. It is old code, using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.*. I am not going to upgrade versions because all I need to do is add a few features and I don't want to break anything (and I'm totally new to Ruby on Rails development, I'm just doing it for this one project). I am getting this error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (Unable to activate climate_control-0.0.3, because activesupport-2.3.11 conflicts with activesupport (>= 3.0).
```

What is it that I need to do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the climate_control [gemspec file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/climate_control/blob/v0.0.3/climate_control.gemspec), the version you are trying to run requires ActiveSupport 3+, which is Rails 3.

Looking through the commit history, it does appear that this gem was ever released for Rails 2, so I think you're either going to have to upgrade Rails, or remove this gem.

Comment: I see now. I'm wondering how he ever used it in the first place then... Seriously weird! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the plugin paperclip depends on cocaine which depends on climate_control which depends on Rails 3. How would I get paperclip to work with all of those dependencies?...

Comment: There is no gemfile, unfortunately, because this is on Rails 2.3.* and the person that created this program did not have a Gemfile. I am just needing to add a few features to the app...however, it's about 3 years old.

Comment: Gemfiles were in use in the 2.3.* days.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I did not realize that. Unfortunately there is no Gemfile. There is a Rakefile, but no Gemfile.

Comment: Well. However the gems were installed, you will have to uninstall Paperclip and re-install whatever version was the last one to work with Rails 2.3.x, and then make sure that all of it's dependencies, and their dependancies, and so on, also work with 2.3.x.  Having a Gemfile would make this process a lot easier.